# why is pandas returning an empty dataframe from this sql query when WHERE clause is used?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I have a python program that uses pandas to write them to a csv, one of the column values I use as the file folder name. One of my columns contains dates in a column that is CAST as just a date in the format of 2018-10-31 and I need the program to generate files for today only. When I add an AND clause with CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) or CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) it returns an empty dataframe, when I remove the AND it works just fine, but builds a CSV containing all of the info for all dates in the table.

my error:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ ScheduleDate,  Vendor, note, WOGFileFolder]
Index: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 85, in <module>
    WOG_folder = pickups_df.at[0, 'WOGFileFolder']
  File "File Path Redacted", line 2141, in __getitem__
    key = self._convert_key(key)
  File "File Path Redacted", line 2227, in _convert_key
    raise ValueError("At based indexing on an non-integer "
ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers
```

my code:

```
stmt_vendor = """
SELECT DISTINCT
Vendor
FROM SOME_DB..SOME_TABLE;"""
cur.execute(stmt_vendor)
partners = cur.fetchall()

for partner in partners:
stmt_vendor_pickup_list = """
SELECT 
    ScheduleDate
    , Vendor
    , note
    , WOGFileFolder
FROM SOME_DB..SOME_TABLE
WHERE Vendor = ?
AND ScheduleDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE
ORDER BY ScheduleDate;"""
pickups_df = pd.read_sql_query(stmt_vendor_pickup_list, conn, params= partner)
logger.infor(pickups_df)
WOG_folder = pickups_df.at[0, 'WOGFileFolder']

vendor_dir = 'FILE_PATH_REDACTED' + WOG_folder

if not os.path.exists(vendor_dir):
    os.mkdir(vendor_dir)
    logger.info("CREATED DIR FOR: " + WOG_folder)
else:
    logger.info("DIR FOR " + WOG_folder + " ALREADY EXISTS")

pickup_file_name = WOG_folder + '_testing.csv'
```

and then the program continues on to build the CSV using this info.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you put the "?" into quotes?

Note that if the backend is postgres, you must use simple quotes

Comment: I'll test that out and see what happens

Comment: When I do that I get an odbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')